# CSS/HTML: Set default container height

Tags: html, css

Hey, how can i set a default container height on a element?

My example have a div like this:

```
<div id="container">
text text
</div>
```

Then i want the height default at 300px; so it gets large even with only this text^.

With DEFAULT i mean also, that if the text exceeds 300px the height should just be bigger like there isnt specified a height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`min-height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-min-height):

```
#container {
    min-height: 300px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/TLNyF/), this features extra css (for aesthetic purposes), but the important part is still the `min-height` declaration.

Comment: min-height is not the same as a default height. I want to provide an initial value not a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

your css should be like this:

```
div#container {
  min-height: 300px;
}
```